# How does my iSight have an exposure value below UVC's GET_MIN?

Tags: macos, usb, video-streaming, webcam, device-driver

I am accessing my Mac's iSight webcam. I would like to set it to a low exposure. Using USB Video Class I was able to query the exposure with GET_MIN and it returned 100. According to USB's documentation found [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs), you cannot set the value below this min. I also tried and it returns `Control request failed:...` error. This makes sense.

What I don't understand is how when I have autoexposure enabled, and I query the exposure value with GET_CUR, the value is 20. How can it be below the minimum? I would like to set it to a value below GET_MIN (i.e. to 20, but manually). Is there a way to do this? Is there a way to change GET_MIN?